# Dynamically Add Row to Table With C#

Tags: c#, html

We are building an automated test suite that outputs results to a simple .html file using a table to output the test script results into an html table

I have no problem creating the file and getting the table header rows to populate.

Here's where I am running into problems: as each test completes it needs to do one of two things:

- Append a `<tr>` row to the existing table in the suite report file

-or-

- Delete the existing table and replace it with a new table with the appended row as each script finished and posts its results

I am using the `HtmlTable`, `HtmlTableRow`, and `HtmlTableCell` classes to get the correct HTML table output from my code.  The problem is getting the table with the appended row up to the page (without having two tables on the page).

Here is the markup of the suite run report with just the header row as it posted by my code.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p style="color:black;font-family:verdana;font-size:15pt;">
            <b>Suite Report</b>
        </p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table id="suiteTable" runat="server">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="border-bottom" style="font-size:10pt;border-color:#808080;">
                     <th style="font-family:verdana;width:400;text-align:left;">
                         <b><u>Test Ran:</u></b>
                     </th>
                    <th style="font-family:verdana;width:400;text-align:left;">
                        <b><u>Test Function Run:</u></b>
                    </th>
                    <th style="font-family:verdana;width:400;text-align:left;">
                        <b><u>Test Result:</u></b>
                    </th>
                    <th style="font-family:verdana;width:400;text-align:left;">
                       <b><u>Test Result Link:</u></b>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the most relevant part of the C# code

```
        tw = new StringWriter();
        sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
        w = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        tableString = null;

        if (isHeader == true)
        {
            tableString = Logging.writeTable(w, inTable, isHeader);
        }
        else
        {
        }

        sw.WriteLine(tableString);
```

The writeTable function goes through and writes all of the markup for the table and all of its rows and cells  into a string where it's then written to the file

What would go in that else part of the if statement to update the  tag in the markup with another  tag to note test results? The isHeader part is fine and I can add rows in the HtmlTable wiht no problem. It's just getting the updated table to page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend you to use an XML + XSL file for this purpose , use an xml file for Test results and an xsl for converting into html

Comment: If you want help with C# code, it would probably be a good idea to post your C# code, not your HTML.

Comment: Done.......Let me know if you need more code

Thanks for the response